# UIAlertController: How to make the right button bolded?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

When I run the following code, the **Yes** button is always on the left side, how can I change it to right side and keep it **bolded**?

```
func showInAppPurchaseAlert() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: "Upgrade?", message: "Do you want to upgrade to pro version?", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "No", style: .default, handler: { action in
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))
    let actionUpgrade = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Yes", style: .cancel, handler: { action in
        self.upgradeToPro()
    })
    alertController.addAction(actionUpgrade)
    alertController.preferredAction = actionUpgrade
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: no, if both buttons are default, they will both become normal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.default` style will always have the right side, and the `.cancel` style the **bold** text. In order for you to change that, you have to set the `preferredAction` like you did in your code, but the problem was that you were using `.cancel` on your "Yes" action, which you wanted on the right side and your "No" action to `.default`. I tried your code, and this version works for me with your requirements.

```
func showInAppPurchaseAlert() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: "Upgrade?", message: "Do you want to upgrade to pro version?", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: { action in
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))
    
    let actionUpgrade = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { action in
        self.upgradeToPro()
    })
    alertController.addAction(actionUpgrade)

    alertController.preferredAction = actionUpgrade

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Note which side each style shows up on also depends on the language direction, ie alerts on devices set to use a right to left language will render differently than on devices using a left to right language (like English).

Comment: Thanks for the addition, in any case the reading direction would match the OP purpose

Answer (score 0):

Pass `.default` for `style:`, it will use the cancel button look and feel.